# Возведение матрицы в квадрат

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Мне нужно умножить массив на самого себя,при этом используя функцию.Я начинающий программист, поэтому не понимаю что не так.
**при запуске выдает массив,но почему то пустой**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int n = 5;
    int arr[n][n];
    int arr1[n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) // столбец
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) //строка
        {
            arr[i][j] = j + 2;
            printf("%d\n", arr1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void matrix(int n)
{
    int arr[n][n];
    int arr1[n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            arr1[i][j] = 0;
            for(int l = 0; l < n; l++)
            {
                arr1[i][j] += arr[i][l] * arr[l][i];
                return arr1[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Начнем с того, что сделанную функцию вы нигде не используете (не вызываете).

Comment: подскажите,пожалуйста,как это можно правильнее сделать.Я пыталась вызывать,но все равно выдает что-то не то.

Comment: `arr[][]` и `arr1[][]` в main() и `matrix()` это **разные массивы**. Вам надо заполнить `arr` в  main, а затем передать эти массивы в matrix, вызвав ее вот так -- `matrix(n, arr, arr1);`, которая скорее всего должны быть вот такой -- `void matrix (int n, int a1[n][n], int a2[n][n]) { ... }` После ее работы используйте сделанный ей в `arr1[][]` результат в main

Comment: Еще у вас интересный возврат из функции — в первой же итерации. Возвращаете не массив, а его элемент. Хотя функция описана, как `void`, т.е. ничего не возвращающая. Ну, вы это не сделали, но порывались — так что на всякий случай напомню, что возвращать указатели/ссылки на локальные переменные функции нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, несколько переделанная ваша программа...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define  n 5

void square(int a[n][n])
{
    int r[n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            r[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
                r[i][j] += a[i][k]*a[k][j];
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            a[i][j] = r[i][j];
}

int main()
{
    int arr[n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) // столбец
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) //строка
        {
            arr[i][j] = j + 2;
            printf("%3d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
    puts("\n");
    square(arr);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) // столбец
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) //строка
        {
            printf("%3d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```